# string to objeto em javascript

Tags: javascript, string

estou recebendo um objeto como parametro, exemplo: "4,5",de uma função, mas preciso trocar a virgula por um ponto. Qnd eu faço isso, o objeto é alterado pra string, entao, preciso voltar essa string para objeto de novo. qnd dou u, alert no typeOf(obj), eu recebo uma string.

```js
var teste = JSON.stringify(editableObj.innerHTML);
teste = teste.replace(/\,/g, '.');
var obj = JSON.parse(teste);
alert(typeof(obj));
```

Comment: Não entendi o que JSON tem a ver com isto, nem qual é seu real problema. Consegue fazer um [mcve]?

Comment: eu recebo um objeto de uma função, ai converto ele para string usando o JSON.stringify, para poder trocar a virgula por ponto, dai preciso converter de volta para objeto apos trocar a virgula por ponto.

Comment: Só com isto não estou vendo como te ajudar. Talvez a solução nem seja esta. Consegue fazer um [mcve]?

Comment: imagine o (editable.innerHTML), como o q eu recebo do formulario na web, ele vem no formato de objeto, e pra ser mais claro o objeto é um valor como: "4,6". dai para eu atualizar o meu banco de dados, se o valor for com virgula, nao funciona. dai q eu preciso trocar a virgula por um ponto. imagine q na segunda linha do código, eu agora tenho um valor= 4.6 e nao 4,6 (com virgula apos user o replace). dai esse valor 4.6 qnd eu uso o alert (typeOf(obg)), eu recebo uma string e nao um objeto como eu precisaria converter de folta pra seguir meu código e fazer o update no banco corretamente.

Comment: Imaginar é mais complicado, um [mcve] é bem mais fácil.

Comment: infelizmente pra vc o codigo está dificil mas pra mim está bem explicado, só nao solucionado.

Answer (score 1):

O valor em `editableObj.innerHTML` não retorna um objeto, sempre que se pega um valor do *HTML* através do `innerHTML`, o retorno é sempre uma `string`. Para confirmar isso digite `alert(typeof(editableObj.innerHTML))`.

`editableObj` é o objeto que representa seu elemento, se for converter o objeto para `string` para fazer as alterações seu código ficaria.

```
var teste = JSON.stringify(editableObj); // passa o Object HTML para string
teste = teste.replace(/\,/g, '.');
var obj = JSON.parse(teste); //Retorna o objeto
alert(typeof(obj));
```

Agora caso queira apenas substituir a `,` por `.`, não tem a necessidade do *JSON*.

```
var teste = editableObj.innerHTML.replace(/\,/g, '.');
editableObj.innerHTML = teste;
alert(typeof(teste));

// string
```

Comment: ok, vc está certo. obg. mas depurando pelo console, percebi q mesmo sendo um objeto no final do codigo alterado, percebo q o valor está "undefined". comparei editableObj com obj e retornou false.

Comment: ao comparar 2 objetos eles sempre serão diferentes, pois o que se é comparado, costuma ser o endereço de memoria de cada um (na maioria das linguagens).

Comment: ok, pode me ajudar mais uma vez a resolver o undefined? obg.